# Why isn't boto returning the number of bytes written to S3?

Tags: python, boto

I'm using boto in a python script. After doing all the setup, I am trying to see if an upload to S3 succeeded by comparing the size of the file on disk with the number of bytes actually written to S3.

(Incidentally, if there's a better way to confirm a successful upload, I'd be happy to know.)

I dropped down to the Python command line and re-produced my problem. After connecting to S3, etc, I did this:

```
>>> bytes = os.path.getsize('file.zip')
>>> key = bucket.new_key('file.zip')
>>> bytesWritten = key.set_contents_from_filename('file.zip')
>>> bytesWritten is None
True
```

[The docs say](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.key.Key.set_contents_from_filename) that the `set_contents_from_filename()` function should return the number of bytes written to S3. Why is it `None`?

(I'm using boto 2.8.0, and yes, the file exists and `bytes` is upward of 200k... I checked.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure at the moment why `set_contents_from_filename` is returning a value of None.  A quick look at the code shows that it is at least trying to return the number of bytes written.  I'll have to run some tests to see if I can reproduce that.

However, if the purpose of checking the bytes is to try to verify that the write operation to S3 completed successfully, there is already a much stronger integrity check built into boto.  Prior to uploading the file, an MD5 checksum of the is calculated.  This is sent as the `Content-MD5` header in the request.  In response, S3 sends an `ETag` header which contains the MD5 checksum that was calculated on the service side for the uploaded content.  Boto compares these and raises an Exception if they do not match.

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't realize the check was built-in. Thank you!